# Is this the proper place to ask about design decisions?

Tags: discussion

I am playing a game, and I noticed a display that seems to interact counterintuitively. Can I ask about the design decisions for making a such a display here? It would look something like "There is this feature that behaves like so, which seems counterintuitive. I would expect it to behave like this instead. Are there any reasons why a designer would choose to make this feature behave the way it does?"

Comment: Probably not. Short of you getting lucky and get an answer from a person who've been involved in the project. Any answers we provide would be mere guesses. It may be more constructive if you reword the question to ask about best practices when it comes to solving a problem and use the game as an example.